# How to get a specific value from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to fill a dictionary using scraped data from a web site, I get the data, then I assigned it to the dictionary, when I print the dictionary the data shows up. I haven't been able to access only one row of the dictionary, what am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print('{:<10} {:<30}'.format('Tiker', 'Price'))
print()
url = 'https://www.coingecko.com/en'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
coin_table = soup.find('div', class_ = 'coingecko-table')

sym = [] 
price = [] 

for coin in coin_table.find_all('tbody'):
rows = coin.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
    token_sym = row.find('span', class_ = 'tw-hidden d-lg-inline font-normal text-3xs ml-2').text.strip()
    token_price = row.find('span', {'data-target' : 'price.price'}).text.strip()

    sym.append(token_sym)
    price.append(token_price)
    

    print('{:<10} {:<30}'.format((token_sym),(token_price)))

    data = dict(zip(sym,price))

print(data)
```

Here is the Output:

```
Tiker      Price

BTC        $44,124
ETH        $3,008.67
USDT       $1.00
BNB        $375.26
ADA        $1.70
XRP        $0.942681
DOGE       $0.255957
USDC       $1.00
DOT        $20.18
UNI        $27.07
BUSD       $1.00
SOL        $40.00
BCH        $598.93
LTC        $163.80
LINK       $24.36
WBTC       $44,081
ICP        $62.06
MATIC      $1.28
ETC        $58.58
XLM        $0.319697
VET        $0.104720
THETA      $6.64
LUNA       $16.00
FIL        $67.32
OKB        $22.29
TRX        $0.081499304270
DAI        $1.00
FTT        $48.11
CUSDC      $0.022222942221
AAVE       $381.38
XMR        $258.06
CETH       $60.28
CDAI       $0.021684507697
EOS        $4.60
CAKE       $18.80
AXS        $69.08
ATOM       $13.65
GRT        $0.793827
SHIB       $0.000007551040
KLAY       $1.43
CRO        $0.138263
NEO        $46.96
BTT        $0.004398147292
AMP        $0.060216111886
MKR        $3,200.18
BSV        $152.82
ALGO       $0.866358
LEO        $2.91
XTZ        $3.27
MIOTA      $0.985600
AVAX       $15.68
CEL        $6.21
EGLD       $125.47
COMP       $445.51
STETH      $2,995.42
KSM        $251.38
HT         $12.63
UST        $1.00
SUSHI      $10.80
DCR        $152.33
HBAR       $0.213998
QNT        $148.47
HOT        $0.010435101561
WAVES      $17.89
RUNE       $6.64
DASH       $172.98
CHZ        $0.330519
HBTC       $43,875
TFUEL      $0.323835
SNX        $10.08
XEM        $0.183840
ZEC        $132.08
XDC        $0.119131
HNT        $15.63
ENJ        $1.51
STX        $1.32
NEAR       $3.09
RVN        $0.139150
YFI        $36,081
TUSD       $1.00
FLOW       $22.20
ZIL        $0.096280701841
IOTX       $0.119378
SAFEMOON   $0.000002055113
TEL        $0.018552432865
CLOUT      $99.89
QTUM       $10.12
BAT        $0.696237
BCHA       $54.61
NEXO       $1.82
MANA       $0.779030
BTG        $57.86
PAX        $1.00
ONE        $0.089852635606
BNT        $3.89
XSUSHI     $12.47
DGB        $0.058679738018
KCS        $10.75
TITAN      $8.35
SC         $0.017170311254
{'BTC': '$44,124', 'ETH': '$3,008.67', 'USDT': '$1.00', 'BNB': '$375.26', 'ADA': '$1.70', 'XRP': '$0.942681', 'DOGE': '$0.255957', 'USDC': '$1.00', 'DOT': '$20.18', 'UNI': '$27.07', 'BUSD': '$1.00', 'SOL': '$40.00', 'BCH': '$598.93', 'LTC': '$163.80', 'LINK': '$24.36', 'WBTC': '$44,081', 'ICP': '$62.06', 'MATIC': '$1.28', 'ETC': '$58.58', 'XLM': '$0.319697', 'VET': '$0.104720', 'THETA': '$6.64', 'LUNA': '$16.00', 'FIL': '$67.32', 'OKB': '$22.29', 'TRX': '$0.081499304270', 'DAI': '$1.00', 'FTT': '$48.11', 'CUSDC': '$0.022222942221', 'AAVE': '$381.38', 'XMR': '$258.06', 'CETH': '$60.28', 'CDAI': '$0.021684507697', 'EOS': '$4.60', 'CAKE': '$18.80', 'AXS': '$69.08', 'ATOM': '$13.65', 'GRT': '$0.793827', 'SHIB': '$0.000007551040', 'KLAY': '$1.43', 'CRO': '$0.138263', 'NEO': '$46.96', 'BTT': '$0.004398147292', 'AMP': '$0.060216111886', 'MKR': '$3,200.18', 'BSV': '$152.82', 'ALGO': '$0.866358', 'LEO': '$2.91', 'XTZ': '$3.27', 'MIOTA': '$0.985600', 'AVAX': '$15.68', 'CEL': '$6.21', 'EGLD': '$125.47', 'COMP': '$445.51', 'STETH': '$2,995.42', 'KSM': '$251.38', 'HT': '$12.63', 'UST': '$1.00', 'SUSHI': '$10.80', 'DCR': '$152.33', 'HBAR': '$0.213998', 'QNT': '$148.47', 'HOT': '$0.010435101561', 'WAVES': '$17.89', 'RUNE': '$6.64', 'DASH': '$172.98', 'CHZ': '$0.330519', 'HBTC': '$43,875', 'TFUEL': '$0.323835', 'SNX': '$10.08', 'XEM': '$0.183840', 'ZEC': '$132.08', 'XDC': '$0.119131', 'HNT': '$15.63', 'ENJ': '$1.51', 'STX': '$1.32', 'NEAR': '$3.09', 'RVN': '$0.139150', 'YFI': '$36,081', 'TUSD': '$1.00', 'FLOW': '$22.20', 'ZIL': '$0.096280701841', 'IOTX': '$0.119378', 'SAFEMOON': '$0.000002055113', 'TEL': '$0.018552432865', 'CLOUT': '$99.89', 'QTUM': '$10.12', 'BAT': '$0.696237', 'BCHA': '$54.61', 'NEXO': '$1.82', 'MANA': '$0.779030', 'BTG': '$57.86', 'PAX': '$1.00', 'ONE': '$0.089852635606', 'BNT': '$3.89', 'XSUSHI': '$12.47', 'DGB': '$0.058679738018', 'KCS': '$10.75', 'TITAN': '$8.35', 'SC': '$0.017170311254'}
```

Desired Result:

```
'BTC': '$44,124'
```

I have tried:

```
print(data)[1]
data.get(0)
```

Also if I take out the `zip` argument when the dictionary is defined I get the error

> data = dict(sym,price) TypeError: dict expected at most 1 argument,
> got 2

also tried to set up the dictionary like this:

```
val = dict(((token_sym,token_price,row)for row in rows))
```

but only returns the last value it don't save all the values in dictionary

Comment: You want to get the 'BTC' row? Do `data['BTC']` if data is the name of the dictionary.

Comment: Wow! that was fast! I tried with `print(data['BTC'])` and it works ! Thank you @xtryingx

Comment: You're expected to [do your research before asking](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953). Retrieving values at a given key from a dictionary is the first thing you learn when learning about dictionaries. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: Hey vp0r. I applaud you for your well structured post. This is not common for first questions ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries use a "key" system rather than relying on indexes like `List` objects do. Reference the key to get the desired value.

Additionally, if you're going to iterate through each of the coins, rather than creating a list of them using `.append()` you might consider creating a dictionary, as this would give you faster lookup.

In your current example you'd have to go over the entire list of data and check if the dictionary is the one you want. If you just make a dictionary you'd be able to do this:

```py
coin_results = {}
for coin in coin_table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = coin.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            token_sym = row.find('span', class_ = 'tw-hidden d-lg-inline font-normal text-3xs ml-2').text.strip()
            token_price = row.find('span', {'data-target' : 'price.price'}).text.strip()
            
            # dictionary creation
            coin_dict = {token_sym: token_price}
            coin_results.update(coin_dict)
```

This would yield:

```py
# Final dictionary
coin_results = {
    'BTC': 'some price data here',
    'other coin here': 'some other price data',
    ...
}

# Access this like: 
coin_results['BTC']
>>> 'some price data here'
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mattdood this is very informative I will keep this aproach in mind during my learning.

Answer (score 0):

Its normal to use the key to access the value in a dictionary. i.e

```
data['BTC']
```

(as xtryingx mentions in the comments)

However, if you don't know the name of the key in advance, but you still want to grab the value against the first key, then you could convert the keys into a list and access that new list by index:

```
list(data)[0] # returns 'BTC'
```

And then use that as the key instead.

Comment: Thats very usefull I don't know  you are able to convert  a dictionary to a list, thats very helpfull too, thank you @Unbridledscum

Answer (score 0):

Get the value:

```py
print(data["BTC"])
```

printing the first row in the format you specified

```py
print(f"{list(data.keys())[0]}: {data[list(data.keys())[0]]}")
```

printing it calling btc

```
print(f"{'BTC'}: {data['BTC']}"
```

you could also change up your data format to a list of key:value pairs such as

```py
[{"BTC": 10000}, {"ETH": 1000}]
```

that way you could easily call indexes as such

```py
>>> x = [{"hi": 123}, {"ho":12}]
>>> x[0]
{'hi': 123}
```